# GRAPH API Post action always shows 'shared a link via app name'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to publish a story through my application. But when I do so it display saying that "Some has shared a link app name" [image: Sample Image]

I don't want it to share as a link but instead something like shown in the following image [image: Desired Result]

Reading through the facebook documents (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) I thought it would be achieved by defining status_type to app_created_story but unfortunately that doesn't help either. Secondly I also want to have "Try it now" button underneth the story like in the second image. I assume its done through "actions" (array of objects containing the name and link) but I am unable to achieve the desired results. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

My code is as follows

```
$attachment = array(
        'access_token'=> "User Access Token",
        'message' => "Message",
        'name' => 'Title',
        'caption' => "Some text",
        'link' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/canvas/',
        'description' => 'Some Text Here',
        'picture' => "http://www.example.com/image.jpg",
        'from' => "application id",
        'status_type' => "app_created_story",


        );
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a user who is logged in and authenticated
    $result = $facebook->api("/userid/feed/",'post',$attachment);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
//$user = null;
}
```

Just to add in the access token i have following three extended permissions: &scope=email,publish_stream,publish_actions

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to publish a story through my application. But when I do so it display saying that "Some has shared a link app name"

That’s because that is exactly what you are doing – you are posting a link.

The second image you’ve shown is not a link post, but an **Open Graph action** – start here to familiarize yourself with the concept: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out. I tried using Open Graph it is showing in my Activity Log but no timeline. Any clues?